# Extensão para Web no Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Instalei o Visual Studio 2012 Express em minha maquina e não adicionei as extensões necessárias para trabalhar na Web.

No Visual Studio existe a opção para adicionar extensões e atualizações. Lá eu localizei várias, porém não sei quais opções instalo para criar um projeto Web Aplication .NET com todos os recursos.

Poderiam me informar quais extensões básicas para rodar um programa Web eu instalo em minha máquina de forma que não tenha problema de falta de extensões no decorrer do desenvolvimento?

Comment: Cara, se você instalou a versão desktop não tem como, né? Visual Studio for Desktop/Windows: desenvolvimento de aplicações para o computador. Visual Studio for Web: versão do VS para desenvolvimento de aplicações para a Web.

Comment: executa o instalador novamente e adiciona/remove recursos. Já que está instalando agora... busque o mais atualizado. Community 2017 https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/

Comment: Eu também recomendo o Visual Studio 2017. Ele corrigiu várias coisas destas versões anteriores. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado amigo! Abrçs!

Answer (score 2):

Poderá usar o Visual Studio 2017. Ele corrigiu várias coisas destas versões anteriores.

No caso escolha:

- ASP.Net e desenvolvimento Web
- Desenvolvimento para Azure
- Processamento e armazenamentos de dados
- Desenvolvimento multiplataforma com .NET Core

[image: Instalador]
[image: Instalador 2]

Com relação a frameworks JavaScript/HTML, poderá usar CDN:

- [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/)
- [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Basicamente no `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ficou bem claro. Muito obrigado amigo! Abrçs!